# Can a function series converges where the sum function is not defined and not continous expandable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence, continuity, taylor-expansion

Consider a real function $f(x)$.  Can the function series of $f(x)$ be convergent where $f(x)$ is not defined "naturally"? More specifically, can the series converge where the function is not defined naturally and not continous expandable?

---

Take for example

$$1+\frac{1-x}{x} \mathrm{log}(1-x)=\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}$$

For $x=0$ and $x=1$ the function $f(x)=1+\frac{1}{1-x} \mathrm{log}(1-x)$ is not defined naturally, but $\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}$ converges for that values of $x$.

Nevertheless $$\mathrm{lim}_{x \to 0} f(x)=0=\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{0^n}{n(n+1)}$$
And

$$\mathrm{lim}_{x \to 1} f(x)=1=\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1^n}{n(n+1)}$$

This means that the function is continuous expandable in $x=0$ and $x=1$.

---

So can I have that a series (of functions) converges where the sum function is not defined, but not even continous expandable?

Comment: Should function series of $f(x)$ converge to $f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is defined? If not, $f(x) = {1 \over sign(x-1)}$ isn't defined for $x=1$. If it should, a sum is a continuous function on any interval where it's defined, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer, in general, is yes. Please note that the function $1+\frac{1}{1-x} \mathrm{log}(1-x)$ is well defined in $0$.

The thing is, the series $\sum_{n \in \Bbb N}^\ \frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}$ is a power series with convergence radius $1$: 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\,a_n}}} = \limsup_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{n(n+1)}} = 1,$$
where $a_n = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$.

Therefore convergence to the function is not guaranteed for $x=1$.